# Work Item type for refactoring duplicate methods (i.e. turning them into 1)

Tags: refactoring, team-foundation-server

Given that you have two identical methods (signatures, body, input/output) that you wanted to refactor into just one, what type of Work Item from the MS Agile template would be most appropriate?  Task, Bug, Quality of Service, Risk?  Why?

Comment: Which template do you mean? [This one](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e)?

Comment: Task, unless the two methods are causing a bug

Comment: @Anna Lear: I believe its this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13038

Comment: @Jon Raynor: write it up as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a user story called "Refactoring duplicate methods" and plan it in an iteration. Then besides only removing this duplicate, also take some time to check on other duplicate items.

If you are sure it is only this only task, then you could have a standing user story and bind a task to it. It is a good practice to have all work attached to a bug or user story.